# How to use LAPS client for local Active Directory on an AzureAD joined laptop to request passwords for other LAPS endpoints on local AD?

Tags: security, microsoft

I've prepared a new laptop that is AzureAD joined, and installed the LAPS client for local Active Directory.

Running the LAPS client results in the message  "LDAP Server is unavailable".

As the laptop is no longer connected to the local Active Directory but straight to AzureAD, **how can I retrieve the local admin password for the other computers / laptops which are still on the local Active Directory** and/or only Azure Hybrid Joined?

Thanks in advance
D

Comment: As stated below, the LAPS client needs to be run on any other Windows endpoint in the network (or VPN) that has full RPC and LDAP connectivity to where the Active Directory domain controllers are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Intune, you could be moving to managing it via Intune. I am not sure if there are any other options for if you are Entra only.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/windows-laps-overview

As for how you could look up the local legacy values. You could establish some kind of RDP, powershell or other type of session to your local domain controllers. Then grab the value from the AD.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. So in other words, I should get rid of the local LAPS software and focus on coding a powershell script to retrieve the password info straight from the local AD for the legacy devices. Is that right ? :)

Comment: I guess this is what you're refering to : 
 `Get-ADComputer -Server DCNAME -Identity COMPUTERNAME -Properties ms-mcs-AdmPwd | Select Name,ms-mcs-AdmPwd`
[reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/vjv1gt/comment/idp68pk/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button)

Comment: @poypoy: the password is stored in an attribute of the computer account in Active Directory. If the endpoint where the LAPS client is run does not have full RPC and LDAP connectivity to the Active Directory domain controllers where the computer account is located, it will not work. The LAPS client needs to be run on any other Windows endpoint in the network (or VPN) where the Active Directory domain controllers are located.